# Is it possble to run a Node.js express api as a windows service

Tags: node.js, express, service

I am making an api with the express module of node.js but instead of using a database which i don't require. Can i run it as a background windows service?

I've looked into node-windows but when i run that as a service is doesn't allowed me call the get methods. is it even possible at all?

if extra info is needed i will edit the question.

Comment: Just wrap `node.exe app.js` in http://nssm.cc/ or srvany? Alternatively, write a Windows Service in Visual Studio that implements ServiceMain and calls `node.exe app.js`.

Comment: I am not able to call the getmethod for example localhost:3000/api when it is run as a service. that's my problem.

Comment: Is the service alive? Can you see node.exe in your process list?

Comment: Yes it is active and running in Services